# get timezone by country code jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to build weather service. Country name that I got from main server came in code format (Like US, UK, CA, etc.) Based on that server info I need to get local time zone by city name. I found Moment js Timezone, but there they using full name of country, so I need to convert country code to full country name or get time zone by city name in other way. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Many countries have several timezones so converting country code to city names may be way of. Just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

this plugin maybe help you...

> https://github.com/scottwater/jquery.detect_timezone

Answer (score 0):

To complete the database included with jquery.detect_timezone
(thanks to Farhad) and your "moment timezone" solution

I've found that maxmind's database provides mapping file between regions and time zones from Olsen database (aka tz database): 
http://www.maxmind.com/timezone.txt

Easy to parse and trying to compare to the full name country !

**EDIT:**

(i just omit to precise the "time" of "zone" is missing, juste the names) :D